# Different versions on website and package manager

Tags: linux, package-management, manjaro

I am currently using Manjaro as my distro. I wanted to install the pulseeffects package. The trouble is the package manager, Pamac (both GUI and CLI), install an older version (4.6.3-1). While the website shows the current release version (4.6.5-1).
https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/pulseeffects/

Please help!

[image: Pamac mackage manager showing version 4.6.3-1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the website

You're looking at the wrong website.

You are using Manjaro, but you link to the website of Arch Linux. These are **different distributions** – they have separate package repositories and different policies as to when new software versions should be packaged and released.

(The relationship is similar to that of Ubuntu vs Debian.)

Although Manjaro periodically *imports* packages from Arch Linux, they are only available in the 'unstable' and 'testing' branches at first. So if you need the new pulseeffects version sooner, [switch to the 'testing' branch](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Switching_Branches) and check if it's available there.

Comment: Ah! My bad. I forgot that!